# Find Diacritics in String (Normalize Strings)

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a list of many names (>1.000.000) which I need to check for diacritics.
Since the dataset is encoded in UTF-8 de-DE I have to consider special characters like `ö,ä,ü`.

Names might also contain characters like `, - ' .` and of course `spaces` for middle names.

This is what I came up with so far:

I take every name and break it up into individual characters rowwise.
Formula for B1: `=ArrayFormula((LOWER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))))`

[image]

The next step is to compare each row in `B` against an array of characters that are allowed - which came to me is a simpler idea than figuring out which characters are not allowed: `{"a"\"b"\"c"\"d"\"e"\"f"\"g"\"h"\"i"\"j"\"k"\"l"\"m"\"n"\"o"\"p"\"q"\"r"\"s"\"t"\"u"\"v"\"w"\"x"\"y"\"z"\"."\"'"\" "\"ö"\"ä"\"ü"\"-"\","}`

[image]

Formula for C: `=ArrayFormula(SUM(--(LOWER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))={"a"\"b"\"c"\"d"\"e"\"f"\"g"\"h"\"i"\"j"\"k"\"l"\"m"\"n"\"o"\"p"\"q"\"r"\"s"\"t"\"u"\"v"\"w"\"x"\"y"\"z"\"."\"'"\" "\"ö"\"ä"\"ü"\"-"\","}))=LEN(A1))` which returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

This approach takes quite some time for this amount of rows. Is there any better, faster, more concise approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,LEN(REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(A1:A), "[a-z \.,-äöü']", ))=0))
```

[image: 0]